# Determining if a given Python module is a built-in module

Tags: python, module, internals, python-internals

I am doing some parsing and introspection of various modules, but I don't want to parse built-in modules. Now, there is no special type for built-in modules like there is a `types.BuiltinFunctionType`, so how do I do this?

```
>>> import CornedBeef
>>> CornedBeef
<module 'CornedBeef' from '/meatish/CornedBeef.pyc'>
>>> CornedBeef.__file__
'/meatish/CornedBeef.pyc'
>>> del CornedBeef.__file__
>>> CornedBeef
<module 'CornedBeef' (built-in)>
```

According to Python, a module is apparently built-in if it doesn't have a `__file__` attribute. Does this mean that `hasattr(SomeModule, '__file__')` is the way to check if a module is built in? Surely, it isn't exactly common to `del SomeModule.__file__`, but is there a more solid way to determine if a module is built-in?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

#### [`sys.builtin_module_names`](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.builtin_module_names)

> A tuple of strings giving the names of
>   all modules that are compiled into
>   this Python interpreter. (This
>   information is not available in any
>   other way — modules.keys() only lists
>   the imported modules.)

Comment: builtin has more than one meaning: 1) shipped along with the python interpreter 2) compiled into the cpython interpreter. The more useful sense is 1, but this answer only applies to 2.

Comment: @bukzor: don't confuse "builtin" and "stdlib" module. And obviously `sys.builtin_module_names` is *not* CPython specific.

Answer (score 11):

If you consider it simply as asked, `builtins`, then the accepted answer is obviously correct.

In my case, I was looking for the standard library as well, by which I mean a list of all importable modules shipped with a given Python distribution. Questions about this have been asked several times but I couldn't find an answer that included everything I was looking for.

My use case was bucketing an arbitrary `x` in a Python `import x` statement as either:

- included in the Python stdlib + built-ins
- installed as a third party module
- neither

This will work for virtualenvs or a global install. It queries the distribution of whatever python binary is running the script. The final chunk does reaches out of a virtualenv, but I consider that the desired behavior.

```
# You may need to use setuptools.distutils depending on Python distribution (from setuptools import distutils)
import distutils
import glob
import os
import pkgutil
import sys    

def get_python_library():

    # Get list of the loaded source modules on sys.path.
    modules = { 
        module
        for _, module, package in list(pkgutil.iter_modules())
        if package is False
    }

    # Glob all the 'top_level.txt' files installed under site-packages.
    site_packages = glob.iglob(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.__file__) 
                    + '/site-packages', '*-info', 'top_level.txt'))

    # Read the files for the import names and remove them from the modules list.
    modules -= {open(txt).read().strip() for txt in site_packages}

    # Get the system packages.
    system_modules = set(sys.builtin_module_names)

    # Get the just the top-level packages from the python install.
    python_root = distutils.sysconfig.get_python_lib(standard_lib=True)
    _, top_level_libs, _ = list(os.walk(python_root))[0]

    return sorted(top_level_libs + list(modules | system_modules))
```

**Returns**

A sorted list of imports: `[..., 'imaplib', 'imghdr', 'imp', 'importlib', 'imputil', 'inspect', 'io', ...]`

**Explanation**:

I broke it up into chunks so the reason each group is needed can be clear.

- `modules`

  - The [`pkgutil.iter_modules`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/pkgutil.html#pkgutil.iter_modules) call scans all loaded modules on `sys.path` and returns a generator of `(module_loader, name, ispkg)` tuples.
  - I turn it into a set and filter out packages, since here we care only about the source modules.
- `site_packages`

  - Get a list of all installed packages under the conventional site-packages directory and remove them from the `modules` list. This roughly corresponds to the third party deps.
  - This was the hardest part to get right. Many things *almost* worked, like [`pip.get_installed_distributions`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31544003/different-list-of-installed-packages-sing-pip-list-and-pip-get-installed-dist) or `site`. But `pip` returns the module names as they are on PyPi, not as they are when imported into a source file. Certain pathological packages would slip through the cracks, like:

    - `requests-futures` which is imported as `requests_futures`.
    - `colors`, which is actually `ansicolors` on PyPi and thus confounds any reasonable heuristic.
  - I am sure that there are certain low-usage modules that do not include the `top_level.txt` in their package. But this covered 100% of my use cases seems to work on everything that is correctly configured.
- `system_modules`

  - If you don't explicitly ask for them, you won't get these system modules, like `sys`, `gc`, `errno` and some other [optional modules](https://docs.python.org/2/library/someos.html).
- `top_level_libs`

  - The [`distutils.sysconfig.get_python_lib(standard_lib=True)`](https://docs.python.org/2/distutils/apiref.html#distutils.sysconfig.get_python_lib) call returns the  top-level directory of the platform independent standard library.
  - These are easy to miss because they might not live under the same python path as the other modules. If you are on OSX and running a virtualenv, these modules will actually be imported from the system install. These modules include `email`, `logging`, `xml` and a few more.

**Conclusion**

For my 2013 MacBookPro I found 403 modules for the `python2.7` install.

```
   >>> print(sys.version)
   2.7.10 (default, Jul 13 2015, 12:05:58)
   [GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.1.0 (clang-602.0.53)]
   >>> print(sys.hexversion)
   34015984
   >>> python_stdlib = get_python_libirary()
   >>> len(python_stdlib)
   403
```

I put up a gist of [the code and output](https://gist.github.com/mateor/89a9cef41532021549739a12eae7790a). If you think I am missing a class or have included a bogus module, I would like to hear about it.

*** Alternatives**

- In writing this post I dug around the `pip` and `setuptools` API. It is possible that this information through a single module but you would really need to know your way around that API.
- Before I started this, I was told that `six` has a function specifically for this problem. It makes sense that might exist but I couldn't find it myself.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `imp.is_builtin` to see if a module name matches a built-in module, but I can't think of any way to actually introspect a module object reliably.

You might also try the following:

```
>>> import imp
>>> f, path, desc = imp.find_module("sys")
>>> desc
('', '', 6)
>>> desc[2] == imp.C_BUILTIN
True
```

Answer (score 2):

When you say, "built-in," do you mean, written in C, or do you mean, part of the standard library?  If you mean the first, then looking for `__file__` is the right thing to do.  As you can see, even the Python interpreter uses the presence of `__file__` as an indicator of built-in-ness.

If you mean "part of the standard library," then it is very hard to determine.