# Different list of installed packages sing 'pip list' and 'pip.get_installed_distributions()'

Tags: python

What is the difference between the command:

```
$ pip list
```

that I can run in a command line, and:

```
import pip
pip.get_installed_distributions()
```

which I run within a `python` environment.

Why do they return a different list of installed packages?

Comment: What does your $PATH have?

Comment: @AnandSKumar how do I check that?

Comment: @AnandSKumar `/home/gabriel/.dropbox-bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games`

Comment: @Gabriel Try doing - `which python` and `which pip` . Let us know the result.

Comment: `which python: /usr/bin/python`; `which pip: /usr/bin/pip`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83896/discussion-between-anand-s-kumar-and-gabriel).

Comment: What happens if you `python -m pip list`?

Comment: This returns the same list as `pip list`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the definition of `pip.get_installed_distributions()` from the [source code](https://github.com/pypa/pip/blob/develop/pip/utils/__init__.py) -

```
def get_installed_distributions(local_only=True,
                                skip=stdlib_pkgs,
                                include_editables=True,
                                editables_only=False,
                                user_only=False):
```

This is run with `local_only` set as `True` by default , whereas when you do `pip list` , it will show all packages local as well as globals, which is what may be happenning in your case and causing you to see much more package installed (both locally as well as globally).

Try running [`pip list --local`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_list.html) to get only locally installed packages

or

```
pip.get_installed_distributions(local_only=False)
```

to get global packages as well.