# Python ImportError: No module named 'requests' after confirming install

Tags: python, importerror

I'm new to python and set up a few things in terminal and am now trying to run python code in Atom.

My first three lines in my code editor are:

```
import re
import requests
import robobrowser
```

When I run the code I keep getting the

> ImportError: No module named robobrowser

I'm assuming it has to do with the path or placement of my files, but I'm not sure how to check that.

Versions I'm running in terminal:

```
(prot) MacBook:prot myname$ python --version
Python 3.7.3
(prot) MacBook:prot myname$ pip --version
pip 19.0.3 from /Users/myname/prot/prot/lib/python3.7/site- 
packages/pip (python 3.7)
```

I also created a virtual env using the following:

```
MacBook:prot myname$ python3 -m venv prot
MacBook:prot myname$ source prot/bin/activate
```

So my default command line displays:

> (prot) MacBook:prot myname$

Running the following shows that the needed packages are there.

```
(prot) MacBook:prot myname$ pip3 list
Package        Version 
-------------- --------
beautifulsoup4 4.7.1   
certifi        2019.3.9
chardet        3.0.4   
idna           2.8     
pip            19.0.3  
requests       2.21.0  
robobrowser    0.5.3   
setuptools     40.8.0  
six            1.12.0  
soupsieve      1.9     
urllib3        1.24.1  
Werkzeug       0.15.1
```

**Edit (updated based on comments):**

```
import sys
print(sys.version)
```

in Atom outputs (used to say 2.#, so I updated the version in atom):

> 3.7.3 (default, Mar 27 2019, 09:23:15)
>
> [GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 10.0.0 (clang-1000.0.42)]

Robobrowser shows up in terminal correctly:

```
(prot) MacBook:prot myname$ pip3 show robobrowser
Name: robobrowser
Version: 0.5.3
Summary: Your friendly neighborhood web scraper
Home-page: https://github.com/jmcarp/robobrowser
Author: Joshua Carp
Author-email: jm.carp@gmail.com
License: MIT
Location: /Users/myname/prot/prot/lib/python3.7/site-packages
Requires: beautifulsoup4, requests, six, Werkzeug
Required-by:
```

To check the remaining robobrowser issue, I ran this in atom:

```
from pip import _internal
_internal.main(['list'])
```

and got this (notice robobrowser is missing):

```
Package         Version 
--------------- --------
cached-property 1.5.1   
certifi         2019.3.9
chardet         3.0.4   
idna            2.8     
pip             19.0.3   
python-dateutil 2.8.0   
requests        2.21.0  
setuptools      40.8.0  
six             1.12.0  
urllib3         1.24.1  
wheel           0.33.1
```

In terminal, running

```
pip show requests
pip show robobrowser
```

returns the same Location

> /Users/myname/prot/prot/lib/python3.7/site-packages

In atom, running

```
import sys
print(sys.path)
```

outputs

> ['', '/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python37.zip', '/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7', '/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages']

So I think I need to add the above location to the sys.path

Comment: What command did you use to create your virtualenv? Did you explicitly use `-p python3`? Are you sure the python interpreter inside the virtualenv is pointing to the correct one? Can you import them separately (e.g. from the IDLE interpreter)? What command are you using to launch your script?

Comment: I edited my post to answer your first question. I'm not sure how to tell if the interpreter is pointing to the correct thing or how to use IDLE. To run the script, I downloaded a package in Atom simply called Script and run it in there and not with terminal.

Comment: update: I configured Script in Atom to use python3 and I got past the 'import requests' line in my code. Still have the issue with 'import robobrowser'.

Comment: @hansence: Try `from robobrowser import RoboBrowser`

Comment: Tried that, got a ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'robobrowser' error

Comment: Edited. Trying to research other threads as well for this issue.

Answer (score 0):

> **Question**: ImportError: No module named 'robobrowser'

Run the following, verify if a `module` can be found **installed** and the `Location` is in the `sys.path`.

```
import sys
import pkg_resources as pkg

sys_path = sys.path
ws_entries = pkg.WorkingSet().entries

print('Python    :{}'.format(sys.version.split('\n')[0]))

key = 'robobrowser'    

key_found = False
for dist in pkg.working_set:        
    if key in dist.key:
        key_found = True
        print('Package   :{}'.format(dist.project_name))
        print('Version   :{}'.format(dist.version))
        print('Location  :{}'.format(dist.location))

        importable = False
        for info in pkg.find_distributions(dist.location, only=True):
            if key in info.key:
                importable = True
                break

        if importable:
            print('Importable: Location were on sys.path')
        else:
            print('Not importable: Unless {} were added to sys.path.'.format(dist.location))

        print('sys.path  :{}'.format(dist.location in sys_path))
        print('WorkingSet.entries:{}'.format(dist.location in ws_entries))
else:
    if not key_found:
        print("No package like '{}' found.".format(key))
```

> **Output**: Example `key = 'requests'`
>
> ```
> Python    : 3.5.3 (default, Jan 19 2017, 14:11:04) 
> Package   : requests
> Version   : 2.19.1
> Location  : /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages
> Importable: Location were on sys.path
> sys.path  : True
> WorkingSet.entries: True
> ```

Comment: @hansence: Yes, and `beautifulsoup4/Werkzeug` are also missing. Compare the `Location` of `pip show requests` with the one from `pip show robobrowser`. Then verify if this `Location` is in `sys.path`. If not add it using `sys.path.append(...`

Comment: The location for requests and robobrowser is the same when I checked in terminal. I don't see that location in sys.path so I'm trying to use that append command.

Comment: Relevant [different-list-of-installed-packages-sing-pip-list-and-pip-get-installed-dist](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31544858/7414759)

Comment: I checked out that thread. Running "pip3 list --local" returns the same list as "pip3 list", but items are missing when I run the "internal list" code in atom. I was just thinking that if this was the issue, then importing requests would be throwing an error but it isn't anymore. I think robobrowser is in the wrong spot but I installed it after setting up my venv.... I could try a simple uninstall and reinstall - that didn't work either

Comment: @hansence: Remove the output, is not usefull at all. It seems even not `dists = [d for d in pkg.working_set]` completes. Should be: `sys.path.append('/Users/myname/prot/prot/lib/python3.7/site-packages')`

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem although not sure if I did so the proper way. I exited the venv and went back to my main directory. Installed robobrowser then went back into the specific venv/directory I was working out of. This solved my issue.

Comment: Does the output of `pip3 show robobrowser` change, different `Location`?

Comment: I had the same location output of `/Users/myname/prot/prot/lib/python3.7/site-packages`

Comment: Does the `print(sys.path)` or `_internal.main(['list'])` change?

Comment: I think robobrowser did show up in the list when I ran the latter in atom afterwards. I worked for a few hours on it yesterday and at one point I had new errors, so I backed out of the prot venv and started over with a new venv so I would have a blank slate. I installed everything again and cloned a zip from github, where before I was copying files one-by-one. My file structure was different with my second venv and things ran a lot smoother. I think my python files were one level too high with my first attempt.