# How to install the os module?

Tags: python

I'm trying to install the `os` Python module on Windows.

In a `cmd` console, I typed:

```
C:\Users\username> pip install os
Collecting os
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement os (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for os
```

So I guessed the module was not available on Windows for some reasons, but I found references of it in some SO questions.

Obviously, typing `Windows` and `os` in Google only gives me answers about Windows itself.

So, how can I install the `os` module on Windows?

---

###### See Also:

<sup>[Determining if a given Python module is a built-in module](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4922520/6045800) - to learn how to check if a library is built-in and hence doesn't require installing.</sup>

Comment: Why are you trying to install it? `os` is part of the standard library, so if you have Python, you have `os` already. https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html

Comment: [`os`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#module-os) is a standard Python module, there's no need install it.

Comment: @MattBall emacs jedi needs it, but doesn't find it
And when in the console, the os functions return `no module named os`

Comment: This sounds like an example of [the XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/133242). I would suggest that you post another question, with the details of the specific error you're seeing, in the context of emacs jedi.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

OS is python's standard library. So no need to download it.

Answer (score 3):

If you are trying to use the `os` library in your Python code and you are getting an error like `NameError: name 'os' is not defined`, you need to make sure you are including an import statement near the top of your Python script to use the os library:

```
import os
```

Answer (score -11):

The Following Line can be pasted in cmd or any terminal to install the module.

```
pip install os-sys
```