# Python sys package not available in conda?

Tags: python, conda, sys

I am trying to install the python **sys** package in my conda 4.13.0 environment on MX-Linux:

```
conda install sys
```

The answer is:

```
PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - sys

Current channels:

  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/linux-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

    https://anaconda.org

and use the search bar at the top of the page
```

The same happens for other common use packages like **os**.

I tried looking for **sys** in https://anaconda.org: I find lots of packages but not the **sys** one.
I expected to find the sys package or a similar one.

Comment: The `sys` package is part of python's standard library, which means it is already installed

Comment: I added it as an answer, you could accept the answer if it works.

Comment: Please don't @RileyMartin. Questions that are basically typos (trying to install a built-in library is kind of a typo), shouldn't be answered but closed. You can flag such questions instead of answering

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install the os module on Windows? (duplicate)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48010748/6045800)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `sys` package is part of python's standard library, which means it comes with python and does not need installed separately.